# Android Wear 2.0 developing a complication

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, android-wear-complication

I've got an existing Android app that I'd like to provide a wear 2.0 complication for. I do not wish to create a custom Wear Watch Face nor a companion Wear app - I simply wish to be able to create a complication that users should be able to add to an existing watch face. Is this possible? Reading the documentation it seems to me that I would need to create a custom Watch Face or an app in order to provide a complication. I'm now a little confused. Any directions on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked [Watch Face Complications](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/complications.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to develop a watch face, but you do need an app running on the watch to deliver a complication. It doesn't need any other UI (such as an `Activity`) unless your complication requires it for configuration, but the `ComplicationProviderService` does need to be in an APK running on the watch.